# Bindings undefined when inside ngIf or other directives Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently this one way binding is showing undefined unless I move the component tag out of all ngIf's or any other directive for that matter.  Why does it do this and what is the best way to get around this so that it will still work without having to move it?  Specifically [columnDefinitions]

```
<h1 class="m-0 mr-2" *ngIf="editObj !== class">
    <div class="class-detail-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <span>{{ class.Description }}</span>
      <div class="csv-buttons d-flex justify-content-around">
        <app-csv-buttons [onValidate]="validateStudent" [onImportRow]="importStudent" [columnDefinitions]="[
           { name: 'Name', isRequired: true },
           { name: 'ExternalID', isRequired: false }
         ]"></app-csv-buttons>
      </div>
    </div>
  </h1>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { BaseComponent } from '../base/base.component';
import { Class } from '../data/class'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-csv-buttons',
  templateUrl: './csv-buttons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./csv-buttons.component.scss']
})
export class CsvButtonsComponent extends BaseComponent implements 
OnInit {
  @Input() onValidate: (row: any) => string;
  @Input() onImportRow: (row: any) => Promise<void>;
  @Input() columnDefinitions: { name: string, isRequired: boolean, 
  validate?: (value: any) => string }[];


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.columnDefinitions)
  }
```

Comment: Unclear to me, what exactly is `undefined`?

Comment: It should not give undefined, nothing wrong with sections you posted, maybe it has to do with your "BaseComponent" ?

Comment: you should read the specs and change the name to avoid problems. 
  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2536. do a console log to troubleshoot

Comment: console.log(this.columnDefinitions) is undefined and I have given it a specific value to be bound to and is what I need to work but any of those Inputs when console logged are undefined as well.  Until I move the <app-csv-buttons></app-csv-buttons> out from being nested in the ngIfs

Comment: Basel Issmail it was the BaseComponent but don't know why.  Thanks.